# Get name of first empty input field returns "undefined" (jquery)

Tags: jquery, input, undefined

I'm running into a problem here with getting the attribute name for the first empty input field. Can't figure out, why he returns "undefined" every time.

```
<input type="text" name="test_1" value="not empty">
<input type="text" name="test_2">
<input type="text" name="test_3" value="not empty">
<input type="text" name="test_4">
<script>alert($('input[value=""]').first().attr("name"));</script>
```

Thanks alot for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The element you're looking to target has no `value` property, hence there are no elements that match the `[value=""]` selector. You need to include that attribute, then the code works fine:

```
<input type="text" name="test_1" value="not empty">
<input type="text" name="test_2" value="">
<input type="text" name="test_3" value="not empty">
<input type="text" name="test_4" value="">
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qLvcn6cd/)

If you do not want to amend the HTML (or cannot amend it) then you would need to use `filter()` to find the elements required by the `value` property, which is always available.

```
var $emptyVal = $('input').filter(function() {
    return !this.value;
});

alert($emptyVal.first().attr("name"))
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qLvcn6cd/3/)

Comment: thanks a lot, man i questioned my sanity, is there an explanation why value="" is not default for input? and you have to explicit put it into the tag?

Comment: There are no default attributes on any elements (although some may be required to keep the HTML valid) whereas the properties of the underlying DOMElement will always exist, even if they are null.

Comment: There's a difference between `value=""`and `value=null`.   If it's not there, then it's not `""` because it's not there.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry - I was answering the question in the comment of why value="" isn't the same as value=null.  I didn't check your answer.

Comment: Ah I see. Well, it improved the logic regardless :)

Comment: I'm looking for code, that finds me the first empty input field. There is no "value" attribute in the html tag. Your second solution doesn't work, just gives me "undefined" again.

Comment: in jsfiddle its working fine, but not in my actual project, but thanks for now, have to figure out, whats the problem in my project

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot Rory McCrossan, you helped me alot.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using `:not[value]` like following.

```js
alert($('input:not([value])').first().attr("name"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="test_1" value="not empty">
<input type="text" name="test_2">
<input type="text" name="test_3" value="not empty">
<input type="text" name="test_4">
```

Comment: thanks alot Azim for the solution, but I found the answer in the other code line from Rory

Comment: You are welcome. I think my code is simpler than other. @egalegal

Comment: yeah its simpler, but didn't work in my project, I will keep it in mind, thanks very much for your time and help